# Consecutive promises not resolving

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I'm working on a project where I use some promises/timeout to delay the call of different functions.

the code of this project is a bit big, so I thought it might be better to make a sample of it and test it and find the reason that is causing the promise ( only last one ) to not resolve.

After making a sample of this code, the same bug that was happening to me occurred again, so it's when I knew that there's something wrong in my logic and wanted to seek some help:

I'll write the code below and explain it after:

```js
let i = 0; // declaring i which help us recall the test method (until a given length)

//function 1 2 and 3 are 3 functions that take few seconds to resolve ( made it simpler for you guys 
// to understand my problem


function function1() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 1");
      res();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function function2() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 2");
      res();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
//in function 3 if the i didn't reach the length given ( made static here=10) it will finish its code
// then call the test method with the new/incremented i
// this keep happening until i= the required length(10) where the function will return true
// and when the function 3 return back true.. the test function should resolve and call the final()
// function

function function3(i) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 3");
      if (i + 1 == 10) {
        res({ bool: true });
      } else {
        i++;
        res({ bool: false, i: i });
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function final() {
  console.log("final");
}

function test(i) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    function1().then((data) => {
      function2().then((data) => {
        function3(i).then((data) => {
          console.log("boolean: ", data.bool);
          if (data.bool) {
            console.log("true..so if");
             res();
          } else {
            console.log("false..so else");
            test(data.i);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }); //end of promise
}

test(i).then(() => {
  final();
});
```

the code runs well and it prints few times consecutively:
from function 1
from function 2
from function 3
....

and here is where the final function should be called to print "final" but its not.
while debugging, I noticed that the function 3 return back false 9 times and true in the last one and this true should cause the test function to resolve but its not.

Comment: `return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    function1().then`  - no need to wrap a function that return a Promise inside a Promise constructor

Comment: you're also nesting .then's rather than chaining them

Comment: because i want them to get called like: function 1...(done ?) call function 2..(done?) call function 3 and this keep happen over and over until a certain  " i " which will cause the test function to resolve and print final at the end

Comment: nesting them worked for me but not chaining ( not sure if its the correct way to do it though)

Comment: also, about your 1st point, im not used to typing it this way, i always return a promise inside a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, in the case of the `else`, you have a *dangling Promise* not connected to anything else:

```
      } else {
        console.log("false..so else");
        test(data.i);
      }
```

The *currently running* `test` function never has its `res` called after the recursive call, so it remains unresolved forever, so the initial call of

```
test(i).then(() => {
  final();
});
```

never results in `final` running.

While you could fix it by adding `test(data.i).then(res)`, to ensure the Promises are all connected:

```js
let i = 0; // delaring i wich help us recall the test method (until a given length)

//function 1 2 and 3 are 3 functions that take few seconds to resolve ( made it simpler for you guys 
// to understand my problem


function function1() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 1");
      res();
    }, 100);
  });
}

function function2() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 2");
      res();
    }, 100);
  });
}
//in function 3 if the i didnt reach the length given ( made static here=10) it will finish its code
// then call the test method with the new/incremented i
// this keep happening until i= the required length(10) where the function will return true
// and when the function 3 return back true.. the test function should resolve and call the final()
// function

function function3(i) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 3");
      if (i + 1 == 10) {
        res({ bool: true });
      } else {
        i++;
        res({ bool: false, i: i });
      }
    }, 200);
  });
}

function final() {
  console.log("final");
}

function test(i) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    function1().then((data) => {
      function2().then((data) => {
        function3(i).then((data) => {
          console.log("boolean: ", data.bool);
          if (data.bool) {
            console.log("true..so if");
            return res();
          } else {
            console.log("false..so else");
            test(data.i).then(res);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }); //end of promise
}

test(i).then(() => {
  final();
});
```

It would be much better to avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern, and avoid the Promise-as-callback antipattern. This can be done concisely by making `test` an `async` function:

```
async function test(i) {
  await function1();
  await function2();
  const data = await function3(i);
  console.log("boolean: ", data.bool);
  if (data.bool) {
    console.log("true..so if");
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("false..so else");
    await test(data.i);
  }
}
```

```js
let i = 0; // delaring i wich help us recall the test method (until a given length)

//function 1 2 and 3 are 3 functions that take few seconds to resolve ( made it simpler for you guys 
// to understand my problem


function function1() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 1");
      res();
    }, 100);
  });
}

function function2() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 2");
      res();
    }, 100);
  });
}
//in function 3 if the i didnt reach the length given ( made static here=10) it will finish its code
// then call the test method with the new/incremented i
// this keep happening until i= the required length(10) where the function will return true
// and when the function 3 return back true.. the test function should resolve and call the final()
// function

function function3(i) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 3");
      if (i + 1 == 10) {
        res({ bool: true });
      } else {
        i++;
        res({ bool: false, i: i });
      }
    }, 200);
  });
}

function final() {
  console.log("final");
}

async function test(i) {
  await function1();
  await function2();
  const data = await function3(i);
  console.log("boolean: ", data.bool);
  if (data.bool) {
    console.log("true..so if");
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("false..so else");
    await test(data.i);
  }
}
test(i).then(() => {
  final();
});
```

Or, if you have to keep using `.then`s:

```
function test(i) {
  return function1()
    .then(function2)
    .then(() => function3(i))
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("boolean: ", data.bool);
      if (data.bool) {
        console.log("true..so if");
        return;
      } else {
        console.log("false..so else");
        return test(data.i);
      }
    });
}
```

```js
let i = 0; // delaring i wich help us recall the test method (until a given length)

//function 1 2 and 3 are 3 functions that take few seconds to resolve ( made it simpler for you guys 
// to understand my problem


function function1() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 1");
      res();
    }, 100);
  });
}

function function2() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 2");
      res();
    }, 100);
  });
}
//in function 3 if the i didnt reach the length given ( made static here=10) it will finish its code
// then call the test method with the new/incremented i
// this keep happening until i= the required length(10) where the function will return true
// and when the function 3 return back true.. the test function should resolve and call the final()
// function

function function3(i) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("from function 3");
      if (i + 1 == 10) {
        res({ bool: true });
      } else {
        i++;
        res({ bool: false, i: i });
      }
    }, 200);
  });
}

function final() {
  console.log("final");
}

function test(i) {
  return function1()
    .then(function2)
    .then(() => function3(i))
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("boolean: ", data.bool);
      if (data.bool) {
        console.log("true..so if");
        return;
      } else {
        console.log("false..so else");
        return test(data.i);
      }
    });
}
test(i).then(() => {
  final();
});
```

Whenever you have a Promise, you should almost always `return` it, or be the initial asynchronous operation of the script.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much <3. i tested it and it worked as expected. so my problem was that ( from what I understood) even if i called resolve (for the 9th call) when the return is true it wont resolve,  because the first calls didnt get resolved.. so the entire function wont get resolved right? and we fixed that using return, also how did we called .then after finishing the test function ? ( even though the test function isnt returning a promise) . and finally  ill definitely take a look into async await in the future... it's syntax seems much clearer.

Comment: Yes *and we fixed that using return* Indeed, returning a Promise to a `.then` callback it's in results in it being waited for properly in the outer Promise chain. The test function *is* returning a Promise - see how it has `return new Promise((res, rej) => {` (in your code). In mine, `return function1()`, since `function1` returns a Promise, and the other Promises are chained off of it, `test1` still returns a Promise. Async functions always return Promises too (which resolve when `return` or the end of the function block is reached)